# two sql Insert then Update not working

Tags: php, mysql

i want to insert data to the database table then update a certain table

`if(isset ($_POST['btnpost'])){
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_announcement(date, subject, event, recipients, status, image, sender)
        Value (NOW(),'$subject','$event','$recipients','$status','$image','$name')";
        $sql="Update tbl_upcoming set status='$stats' where upcoming_id='$aid'";
}`

but this code only execute the insert statement.
how to do it right guys ..TY!

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with this code:

```
if(isset ($_POST['btnpost'])){
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_announcement(`date`, `subject`,`event`, `recipients`, `status`, `image`, `sender`)
        Value ('NOW()','".$subject."','".$event."','".$recipients."','".$status."','".$image."','".$name."')";
        $sql="Update tbl_upcoming set status='".$stats."' where upcoming_id='".$aid."'";
}
```

if it will not work replace`'NOW()'` with `NOW()`